# What can give rocket salad (Eruca Sativa) a fish smell?

Tags: botany, vegetable

I bought an 'already washed' plastic tray of rocket salad (arugula, or [*Eruca Sativa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eruca_sativa)) enclosed in a sealed plastic bag. It has been kept in the refrigerator for four days. When I opened it, some 12 days before the "best before" date,  I noticed a strong smell of fish.

I am a regular consumer of this sort of vegetable, I also have some in my garden, so I know how it smells. Yet, by searching on the net I realized that other people have lamented this fish smell in their pre-washed arugula salads.

I am wondering now where does this fish odor come from? Can it come from the plant itself, or is it a side-effect of industrial washing? What exactly is giving this smell? Bacteria, molds, natural decomposition of the plant's essences, or something else?

(Following my instinct I threw the salad away, but I did taste a few leaves and it did not taste 'bad' or 'foul'. It was just the smell that was off.)

Comment: A lot of people report a bad smell/taste from arugula when it gets too big, the leaves are best when they are very young. (I don't mean time since picked, I mean time since sprouted) No idea if this is the same thing you are reporting or anything about your source for arugula.

Comment: Note: rocket salad is often not Eruca sativa, but some Diplotaxis, because the later growth quicker. My guest it the the water used: it could contains some algea which gives such smell. Days in plastic is an ideal environment (for the few algae in the original water).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete guess - the arugula could contain or be decomposing into amine-containing compounds (known to have a fishy smell).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amine#Physical_properties

Comment: Not a bad guess if you ask me, considering the [seeds contain amino acid](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/288705614_Chemical_composition_including_amino_acid_fatty_acid_and_glucosinolate_profile_of_taramira_Eruca_sativa_oilseed)